# Mongoose sorting numbers wrong way

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a simple Schema in mongoose:

```
var ShotSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  code: Number,
  active: Boolean
});
```

After running this static function to sort query by code number:

```
findShotMax: function(seq, cb) {
  this.find({sequence: seq})
  .sort('code')
  // .limit(1)
  .exec(cb);
}
```

I get shots sorted in a weird way:

```
10,
100,
110,
120,
140,
20,
30,
40,
....
```

How to fix the order to work in a normal fashion?

Comment: Did you save all your documents to the database using that schema, or did the data already exist in a collection? It looks like its stored as strings instead of numbers.

Comment: Correct, it was stored as strings value previously. Is that causing a problem? Do I need to perform some type conversion?

Comment: Yes, that's causing the problem. You have to convert the data in your database from strings to numbers (Mongoose has little to do with sorting, that's all being done inside the MongoDB server).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have I guess stored the data into sting first and then created the schema.

First you need to convert string into integers. Use following :

```
db.shortCollection.find({}).forEach(function(obj) {
    obj.code = new NumberInt(obj.code);
    db.shortCollection.save(obj);
});
```

And then you can try your query again.